# Middleware scoped to a route in MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

How can be written middleware that is executed on specific routes using MVC 6? This can be done in the precious version of the WebAPI using a DelegatingHandler, I can't find a way of doing it in MVC 6 though.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should do it I think

```
PathString path = new PathString("/somefolder");
app.Map(path,
appBranch =>
{
    // add middleware needed for this branch

});
```

Comment: Just FYI...you should be able to say `app.Map("/blah",...` as PathString allows you to get directly assign a string which gets converted to PathString https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Abstractions/PathString.cs#L268

Comment: And how about parameters, like "/blah/{id}" ? Are they working?